# How to insert a data url/binary to replace an image in a libreoffice writer document?

Tags: java, libreoffice, uno, libreoffice-writer

I am creating a report printer in Java using the LibreOffice SDK and Apache Batik. Using Batik, I draw svgs which I then insert into a LibreOffice Writer document. To properly insert the image, all I found is using a path to load the image from disk and insert it into the document. So far so good, but I have to explicitly save the document to disk in order to read it into libreoffice again.

I tried to use a data url as the image path but it did not work. Are there any possibilities to read an image from a stream or anything else I can use without storing the file to disk?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I realized how to do it when I realized that all my images I added were just image links. So I had to embed the images instead.

To use this, you need:

- Access to the XComponentContext
- A TextGraphicObject in your document (see the links above)
- The image as byte[] or use another stream

The code:

```
Object graphicProviderObject = xComponentContext.getServiceManager().createInstanceWithContext(
"com.sun.star.graphic.GraphicProvider",
xComponentContext);

XGraphicProvider xGraphicProvider = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
XGraphicProvider.class, graphicProviderObject);

PropertyValue[] v = new PropertyValue[1];
v[0] = new PropertyValue();
v[0].Name = "InputStream";
v[0].Value = new ByteArrayToXInputStreamAdapter(imageAsByteArray);

XGraphic graphic = xGraphicProvider.queryGraphic(v);
if (graphic == null) {
LOGGER.error("Error loading the image");
return;
}

XPropertySet xProps = (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
XPropertySet.class, textGraphicObject);

// Set the image
xProps.setPropertyValue("Graphic", graphic);
```

This worked effortlessly even for my svg images.

Source: https://blog.oio.de/2010/05/14/embed-an-image-into-an-openoffice-org-writer-document/